# AutoMockContainer - Error when calling controller

Tags: moq, automocking, moqcontrib

Been playing around with AutoMocking.

While using moq.contrib.indy am getting the following error when calling the controller

{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: controllerContext"}

```
var mocks = new AutoMockContainer(new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose));
mocks.GetMock<IAccountService>().Setup(x => x.AddSweepstake(new AddSweepstakeViewModel()));
mocks.GetMock<IRepository<Account>>().Setup(x => x.SaveOrUpdate(new Account())).Returns(new Account()).Verifiable();

mocks.Create<AccountController>().AddSweepstake(new AddSweepstakeViewModel()); //fails on this line
```

Normally would do like this

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
```

How do I mock the controller context for this with AutoMocking?

Comment: I think it's very difficult to figure out what your issue is with this example--it depends on how these objects are defined. If possible, please post an entire runnable solution that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Did you try container.Resolve<ControllerContext>() ?